# Can HP QTP & FuncUnit/Selenium coexist, or are they mutually exclusive?

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, qtp, javascriptmvc

QTP seems robust and integrated withother systems.Funcunit/Selenium seem easier/quicker to setup and run for developers. Is it either-or, or is each tool betterat differentaspects of programming?

Anyone had experience with using both on a project and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage that QTP has vs Selenium is that QTP supports automation against non-browser-based applications. Selenium only tests web apps hosted in a browser.

Technology-wise, they can coexist, but I am not sure why you would want to. If you are a shop that only has web apps, then you could use either. If you are a shop that also needs to support desktop apps, then you should use QTP (or another vendor tool that supports both, like IBM RFT or MSFT VS2010).

In my opinion, you would never want to use both (i.e. QTP for desktop, Selenium for web), as you then need to support expertise in 2 toolsets.